# List All Enqueued Scripts and Styles

Tags: wp-admin, scripts, css

Is there any way to list which scripts and styles have been enqueued, while within wp-admin?

For example this code works, but only if you are on the frontend. How could I get the same list while staying in wp-admin?

```
function dc_list_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $enqueued_scripts = array();
    foreach ( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) {
            $enqueued_scripts[ $handle ]['handle'] = $wp_scripts->registered[ $handle ]->handle;
            $enqueued_scripts[ $handle ]['src'] = $wp_scripts->registered[ $handle ]->src;
    }
    print_r( $enqueued_scripts );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dc_list_scripts' );
```

If I run the above code in wp-admin then I get a list of scripts and styles enqueued within wp-admin. That's not what I want, I need to know which resources are enqueued for the frontend.

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now would be to add an extra function that runs when in the frontend, go through `$wp_scripts->queue` and store them in a transient. Then in the dashboard just get the values from that transient. I can't think of a way to get the frontend scripts without actually loading the frontend - unless of course you make an ajax call to the home URL for example, and then in the ajax callback populate the list of scripts which you can use in your admin page.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more doing it via an extra ajax call makes sense

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/233142/120712

Comment: @Vishwa the related threads only works on the frontend, my question pertains to the admin area.

Comment: @DannyCooper Can you elaborate why this should not work here? `add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    $scripts = wp_scripts();

    var_dump($scripts->queue);
    wp_die();
}, PHP_INT_MAX)` resulted in some scripts. Though some were missing, there might be more things to consider than `queue`

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320065/get-the-list-of-enqueued-registered-scripts-for-a-specific-post Check out the solution given in the above link